# How to register many accounts on social networks for each website you wish to rank?

Tags: social-media, link-building

Google changed the rule, now it's hard to get position on first page.

Many people use a paid blog network (PBN); but if you have many websites such as 50, 100, or above; without link building they will not give you powerful links.

If you build many links to every website, you need many social network accounts: Google+, Facebook, Twitter, etc. How do you do that?

Comment: please re-phrase your question. The question above seems more like a rant.

Answer (score 2):

The approved way to create a presence on social networks for each site that you own is to create a "page" for each of your websites.

On Facebook, visit https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/pages and use the "+ Create a Page" button.  When I do so, I use the "Brand or Product" option and then choose "Website" as the subcategory.

On Google+, there is a "Home" drop down menu under the logo where you can select "Pages" and then "Create a page".  Again, you can use "Product or brand" and then "Website".